# VMware and Oracle

Tags: oracle, vmware

VMware is supported by Oracle but not certified. That I get, but why does it matter anyway? Because support is the only thing matters and how will Oracle know that I'm on VMware? Either way, they will support in case of issues right? Why is there a big fuss about VMware and Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

- "VMware is supported by Oracle but not certified." Oracle does not certify VMware but it does not certify any hardware, too.
- "how will Oracle know that I'm on VMware": I don't know if Oracle support can find out that you are running on VMware if they analyze the output of their RS (remote diagnostic agent). In many situations it is not relevant on which hardware your system is running. But if it is relevant it does not make sense to disguise the hardware/virutal system. Oracle can ask you to reproduce the problem on a non virtual system if they suspect that the error is caused by the virtualisation.
- "they will support in case of issues" yes, they will
- "Why is there a big fuss about VMware and Oracle" Because of Oracle's license policy. As far as I know Oracle's point of view is that ou have to license the whole machine or  the whole cluster even if  you run an oracle database in only one virtual machine. Search the web for this topic!

Comment: Good one and its true they dont certify anything other than what they own but just curious does it matter on what storage im on..if it is some very new hyper convergence system.. Will oralce ask for its details and support?